# ZoKrates witness computation

Tags: ether, zokrates

What do the values provided with the -a option in ZoKrates witness computation represent? Are these values typically private to each user or public, similar to verification keys?

Also how are they generated?

The picture below shows a screenshot from the ZoKrates CMD on windows 10

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Zokrates, so let provide a partially generic answer.

I assume this is related to proof generation. When generating proofs, depending on the used ZK proving system, your program (circuit?) can have public and private inputs.

For example, if you have a ZK program which is used to prove that you know `a` such that `a ^ b = c`, then `a` is private and `b` and `c` are public.

Since `a` should stay private, you need to generate the proof on your machine. If everything was public, you could just send the values somewhere and another entity could generate the proof for you. Witness generation is a part of the proof generation process.